# Any way to communicate with a Vernier Labquest mini?

Tags: java, c++, serial-port, usb

Vernier uses their own custom software in windows. But their device is a USB, no doubt a serial port of some kind.  I tried to list out the connected serial ports in Processing, and nothing showed up.

I have asked Vernier if they provide drivers, but I am assuming they are not going to help.  So I want to know whether anyone knows how to communicate with Vernier devices without support?

I would prefer the answer to be in terms of Java or C++, but I'll take anything really.

Comment: I think you're punching above your weight. Reverse Engineering is non-trivial, and if you had sufficient experience you would have already established the USB device class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vernier does in fact have a custom driver library in C which they claim is accessible from C++ and Java. I haven't looked into it yet to see how it works, but it is clearly totally non-standard stuff, most definitely not a standard USB serial device.